# Gridview child click to update User Interface android

Tags: android, gridview, click

I have created one gridview and use custom adapter for that. I added two images inside grid view.one is image and another one looks like close button. My plan is to remove the item from the gridview if we click the close button and it's working.I have one textview above gridview to show number of items in gridview.But I'm not able to update the number of items text view while deleting. Please help me to find how to update User Interface. My code is like below

```
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    View MyView = convertView;
    pos=position;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) MyContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_for_bag, null);


        ImageView iv = (ImageView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_bag_image);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sampleImage);

        ImageView close = (ImageView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_bag_close);
        close.setImageResource(R.drawable.closeicon);

            close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    BagList.deleteItem(pos);

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });



    }

    return MyView;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming You have reference to Your text view somewhere in activity which has the grid.

The main idea - to have own DataSetObserver on Your adapter.

It should looks like the following code:

```
// Your activity

// It's Your grid
GridView gridView;
// It's Your text view
TextView numberOfItems;
// It's Your adapter
BaseAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter();

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.patient_name_enter_screen);

    // Init gridView and numberOfItems
    ...

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {

            // Here we know that the adapter was updated
            textView.setText(adapter.getCount());
        }
    };)

    ...
}
```